# iText - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators

Tags: itext

I receive the error message "**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unbalanced save/restore state Operators**", when I try to use **setClip**(...) several times during drawing with a Graphics2-object, which I got from iText's cb.createGraphics(..).

Additional Information:

- single threaded application
- error after 10 calls to setClip()
- allways a pair setClip(*path*) and setClip(null)
- occurs with version 2.1.4; with Version 2.1.7 the error even appears earlier
- without the setClip(...) everything is drawn as expected without errors

Does anybody know a solution for this problem, or has a hint to it?
Does this error appear in Version 5..., too? (Before I buy a licence for version 5 ;-)

Thank you!

```html
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\test.pdf");
                Document document = null;
                Rectangle rect=PageSize.A3.rotate();
                document = new Document(rect);
                PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
                document.open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                Graphics2D g =cb.createGraphics(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
                int x[]={10,1000,1000,10};
                int y[]={10,10,1000,1000};
                Polygon po=new Polygon();
                for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
                po.addPoint(x[i],y[i]);
                g.clip(po);
                g.setClip(null);
                document.newPage();
                g.clip(po);
                g.setClip(null);
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Why not test with iText 5? Surely you don't need a license just to test the library. Note the unbalanced save/restore exceptions are usually caused by bugs *outside* iText, so seeing your code or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally could extract the necessary steps to produce the error: see the code above. 

The exception is thrown with the last line g.setclip(null);

It does not depend on the filename or the numbers.

Comment: Before going to the next page (`document.newPage()`) you have to dispose `g`. On the new page you can get a new `Graphics2D`. Each page is an individual canvas.

Comment: Thank you. It works, as you said! But I do not understand, why it worked ok with any other graphic commands - except the setClip() - using the way of th code snippet (getting the Graphics2D only once).